# Should I use OnAfterRenderAsync instead of OnInitializedAsync?

Tags: c#, blazor

In a Blazor server component, I use `OnInitializedAsync()` to connect an event from an injected service:

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _fooRepository.SomethingChanged += OnSomethingChanged;
    await Refresh();
}

public void Dispose()
{
    _fooRepository.SomethingChanged -= OnSomethingChanged;
}

private async Task Refresh()
{
    this.FooData = await LoadDataFromRepository();
}
```

Unfortunately, according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0), the `OnInitializedAsync` method may be called twice, depending on the render mode.

I found some examples that recommend using `OnAfterRenderAsync` for the initialization logic instead:

```cs
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        _fooRepository.SomethingChanged += OnSomethingChanged;
        await Refresh();
    }
}

[... Dispose and Refresh as above... ]
```

Are there disadvantages when using `OnAfterRenderAsync` instead of `OnInitializedAsync`? It seems to me that I should abandon `OnInitializedAsync` and default to `OnAfterRenderAsync` instead.

Comment: Some parts will still render twice. When rendering has finished, and you still need to populate the component, changing the state by adding data will render what has changed in the component again. I also want to change this in my project, so I'll play around a bit and post my findings.

Comment: It will  only be called twice if you have PreRendering enabled and this component was either the root or on the page requested for a new connection.

Comment: You wouldn't be having this problem if you used Blazor state in a one-way manner. There would be no need for such explicit event handling. If the data flows down from the parent through `Parameter`s, the component would be refreshed automatically.

Comment: Check [Bind across more than two components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#bind-across-more-than-two-components-1): the data is stored by the parent, change notifications flow upward and new data values flow downward.

Comment: 'You wouldn't be having this problem if you used Blazor state in a one-way manner.'  How is it different from the flux pattern? https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/in-depth-overview/

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, sorry, comrade,  but I think you misunderstood this simple question...

Comment: @enet that's why I asked the OP to clarify. This is unusual code for a Blazor application. Preventing double loading is easy (check whether FooData is null) but avoiding leaked event handlers is more difficult.

Comment: Yes the component get's rendered twice - once on server to build the static page, and then again when the SPA loads.  This only happens when the first page of the SPA loads.  But it doesn't matter.  The first cycle loads, and then disposes of the component, so there's no real problem.  I always use `OnInitialized{Async}` for registering event handlers, but at the moment I can't think of a valid reason not to use `OnAftrrRender{Async}` other than "it don't seem right".  Anyone think of any?

Comment: If that is the case, then one should not worry about the leaky event handlers? The handler will be unhooked with Dispose() anyway. Then the only problematic thing is the cost/response penalty of running a time-consuming Load() operation?

Comment: Correct there is no leak.  And as for time consuming, if that worries you keep the landing page short and sweet.

Comment: Yes! That's why you would use another service where you initialize and store your state; in the component simply access it. OR use something elaborate like fluxor (flux for blazor). Why are people downvoting my answer!

Comment: I think it's because the question is not about services and state, but about event handlers, where to register them and pre-rendering.  Forget `this.FooData = await LoadDataFromRepository();` it's just some pseudo code.

Comment: I just looked into the fluxor source code. The FluxorComponent does exactly what I do: OnInitialized subscribes to some event and Dispose cleans up the subscription. However, the question is about initialization and OnInitialized vs OnAfterRender, so I guess we stop the discussion about event connections and data updates.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Note.  As this is an active answer, it was updated on 5-Sep-2023 by the author to incorporate comments on *OnAfterRender* with the advice in point 3 revised.

It's important to understand what's going on with pre-rendering.

The page is rendered twice:

1. Once by the server to build a static version of the page.  This loads and then disposes of all the components correctly.
2. A second time by the Blazor Hub session when a SignalR session is established by `blazor.server.js` running in the browser session.

Points:

1. These two loads are totally separate, and there's no leaks with registering/unregistering event handlers.
2. This only happens when the application first loads.  After than it's one load per page.
3. `OnInitialized{Async}` is the natural place for registering event handlers.  You should not implement them in `OnAfterRender{Async}`.  Why not? You should register them within the `OnInitialized{Async}/OnParametersSet{Async}` process, not in a UI event process [see the detailed information below].

If you're worried about load time with rendering a page twice, keep the landing page short and sweet.

A final comment.  In your code, do the initial load of your data and then register for the `SomethingChanged` event.

**On OnAfterRender**

`OnAfterRender{Async}` is part of the DOM event process, not the `OnInitialized{Async}/OnParametersSet{Async}` process.  It's driven by the Renderer receiving a DOM updated event from the DOM.  While `OnInitialized{Async}/OnParametersSet{Async}` may trigger a render event [through calling `StateHasChanged`, and thus eventually a `OnAfterRender{Async}` event once that render has occured],  the two are not directly coupled.  `OnAfterRender{Async}` is part of another process, so there is no guarantee when it's run.

In general you should only use `OnAfterRender{Async}` to do JSInterop stuff.  Doing anything in `OnAfterRender{Async}` that mutates the state of the component [and inevitably necessitates another call the `StateHasChanged` and another render and another `OnAfterRender{Async}`] is illogical.  All  state mutation should happen in `OnInitialized{Async}/OnParametersSet{Async}`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. To me, the documentation sounded as if the two OnInitializedAsync calls occur on the same component instance followed by a single Dispose. Your first point corrects this misunderstanding :) The second point, that the double initialize only happens once when the app first loads, is also reassuring. I will keep OnInitializedAsync instead of OnAfterRender, because as you say, it seems more natural.