# How do I show a loading indicator while images are loading for a Blazor Server application?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm working on Blazor Server project which has to load images from a private blob storage location, and display them to the user, according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/images?view=aspnetcore-7.0#stream-image-data) the way to do this, is to create a JS interop function which handles the streaming part to the client, and have it fill in the `<img>` `src` attribute when the streaming is complete. The interop function then gets called in the `OnAfterRenderAsync` lifecycle override (this last part wasn't clear from the docs, since they used a button press to trigger loading of the images, and thus might be a wrong conclusion of myself).

As there are multiple images which must be loaded, this can take a while, depending on the user's connection. Therefor  I would like to display some alternate HTML like a loading spinner or similar, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Perhaps beyond the scope of this question, but expanding on it: It's clear to me that Blazor rendering happens synchronously, and offers some pre-/post-render lifecycle hooks which can run be used to perform asynchronous calls. But how do components like e.g. [MudBlazor's Table component, which offers server-side filtering,sorting, etc...](https://mudblazor.com/components/table#record-type-support) accomplish this with asynchronous calls?

I created a [minimal example](https://github.com/vyruz1986/BlazorImageLoading) which demonstrates what I'm trying to accomplish, I started from the basic `dotnet new blazorserver` project and added the page below, as well as [the JS interop file as shown in the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/images?view=aspnetcore-7.0#stream-image-data):

```csharp
@page "/images"
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<div>
    @foreach(var imageSrc in ImageSources)
    {
        <div>
            <img hidden="@(!imageSrc.Loaded)" id="@imageSrc.Id" />
            @if(!imageSrc.Loaded)
            {
                <span>Loading...</span>
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code {
    private List<ImageSource> ImageSources = new(){
        new(Guid.NewGuid(), "https://picsum.photos/200/300"),
        new(Guid.NewGuid(), "https://picsum.photos/200/300"),
        new(Guid.NewGuid(), "https://picsum.photos/200/300"),
        new(Guid.NewGuid(), "https://picsum.photos/200/300")
    };

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        foreach(var imageSrc in ImageSources)
        {
            var stream = await Http.GetStreamAsync(imageSrc.Url);
            await SetImage(imageSrc.Id.ToString(), stream);
            imageSrc.Loaded = true;
        }
    }
    public async Task SetImage(string imageElementId, Stream imageStream)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        var dotnetImageStream = new DotNetStreamReference(imageStream);
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("setImage", imageElementId, dotnetImageStream);
    }

    public record ImageSource(Guid Id, string Url)
    {
        public bool Loaded {get;set;}
    }
}
```

This example should run fine for anyone with .NET 7 installed by just running `dotnet watch run` in the repo's root.

To be clear, this code works without the conditional 'Loading...' `span` and hiding of the `img` element, but with the code as above, I just get 4 times 'Loading...' on the page forever.
So it seems like Blazor is not re-evaluating the `Loaded` property of the `ImageSource` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> with the code as above, I just get 4 times 'Loading...' on the page forever.

OnAfterRender is unlike the other lifecycle events in that it does not do any implicit StateHasChanged() calls. If it did you'd have an endless loop. Your code runs that risk too, you need to use firstRender

```cs
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
  if(firstRender) // only once
  {
    foreach(var imageSrc in ImageSources)
    {
        using var stream = await Http.GetStreamAsync(imageSrc.Url); // using
        await SetImage(imageSrc.Id.ToString(), stream);
        imageSrc.Loaded = true;
        StateHasChanged();       // render again 
    }
  }
}
```

And both the Stream and the DotNetStreamReference are IDisposable resources, add `using` to be safe.

```cs
public async Task SetImage(string imageElementId, Stream imageStream)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    using var dotnetImageStream = new   DotNetStreamReference(imageStream);  // using 
    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("setImage", imageElementId, dotnetImageStream);
}
```

Comment: Spot on, thanks a bunch!

Comment: [Snippet](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/8ah5jb44) Here in case anyone wants to test it out.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69374767/should-i-use-onafterrenderasync-instead-of-oninitializedasync and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76442472/blazor-should-i-read-in-my-data-in-oninitializedasync-or-onafterrenderasync and many more answers on the OnAfterRender subject.

Comment: @Alex - note that I've added 2 `using` s , I'm pretty sure you need it here.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this where you encapsulate the image logic into a component.  The C# code is in `OnParametersSetAsync` and only the JS interop code runs in `OnAftetRenderAsync` with no need to manually call `StateHasChanged`.  Everything runs within the normal component lifecycle and events.

I've taken this approach over doing all the work in `OnAfterRenderAsync` because `OnAfterRenderAsync` is not part of the component `SetParametersAsync` process and therefore not part of `OnInitialized{Async}/OnParametersSet{Async}`.  It's an event that gets raised from the browser when a render process driven by the Renderer is complete.  There is no guarantee when it runs.

[Personal view] I think it's bad practice to run code that belongs in the lifecycle methods in a UI event. `OnAfterRenderAsync` is for JsInterop stuff that doesn't mutate data within the component which then needs another Render to get displayed.  In the code below the only mutation is to `_imageToRender` which is there to control the JSsInterop code logic,  not the component UI logic.

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@inject IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory

<div>
    <img hidden="@(!_loaded)" id="@_uid" />
    @if (!_loaded)
    {
        <span>Loading...</span>
    }
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Url { get; set; }

    private bool _loaded;
    private bool _imageToRender;
    private string _uid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    private Stream? _stream;
    private string? _currentUrl;

    protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        // Detect any Url changes and update on change
        if (_currentUrl != this.Url)
        {
            _loaded = false;
            using var http = this.ClientFactory.CreateClient();
            _stream = await http.GetStreamAsync(this.Url);
            // First remder happens here on the async yield
            _loaded = true;
            _currentUrl = this.Url;
            _imageToRender = true;
            // second render hsappens on completion 
        }
    }

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        // Only update the image if we've had a change and a completed stream to use
        if (_imageToRender && _stream is not null)
        {
            var streamRef = new DotNetStreamReference(_stream);
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("setImage", _uid, streamRef);
            // clean up and set flags
            _stream.Dispose();
            streamRef.Dispose();
            streamRef = null;
            _stream = null;
            _imageToRender = false;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
@page "/counter"

<div>
    @foreach (var imageSrc in ImageSources)
    {
        <Image Url="@imageSrc.Url" />
    }
</div>

@code {
    private List<ImageSource> ImageSources = new(){
        new("https://picsum.photos/200/300"),
        new("https://picsum.photos/200/300"),
        new("https://picsum.photos/200/300"),
        new("https://picsum.photos/200/300")
    };

    public record ImageSource(string Url) { }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering about _not_ closing or disposing the _stream  and streamRef  here. It'll work but I think this could leak memory or resources.

Comment: No wondering required! Remise of me to overlook.  Updated with disposals.