# Blazor Server / .NET 8 / Calling async code on initial load is freezing the screen until first async call is completed?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I'm trying to start using .NET 8 Blazor Server/Client on my new project.

I have a template from Sync Fusion and I have added ASP.NET identity functionality.

I'm trying to make a Blazor Server page that returns my server logs.

I log in, then go to the page and I expect to see the Loading... while the data loads.

Well it seems to display the Loading... after the return from my database and then fires the database call again and then finally shows the grid with data.

What am I doing wrong?

I removed the database call and then did a `Task.Delay(1000)` and it did the same thing.

I thought the entire point was that it could show the loading until the list of my object is set from the database and then will display the grid?

**Seri-Log.Razor page:**

```
@page "/maintenance/seri-log-server"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using App.Client.Services
@using System.Net.Http.Headers
@using App.Shared.DTOs.SeriLog
@using App.Shared.Interfaces
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons
@using System.Text.Json
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids
@using System.Net.Http.Json

@inject ILogger<SeriLogsServer> _logger;
@inject IMaintenanceStore maintenanceStore;

@attribute [Authorize]

<PageTitle>Seri Log Maintenance Server</PageTitle>


<h3>Start Local: @CurrenTimeLocalStart</h3>
<hr />

@if (Error != null)
{
    <div class="c-error">
        <h3>Error</h3>
        <h5>@Error</h5>
    </div>
}

@if (SeriLogs == null)
{
    <span>
        Loading Seri Logs......
    </span>
}
else
{
    <hr />
    <h3>End Local: @CurrenTimeLocalEnd</h3>
    <SfGrid ID="Grid" DataSource="@SeriLogs" @ref="Grid" AllowPaging="true" AllowFiltering="true" AllowReordering="true" AllowResizing="true" AllowGrouping="true" AllowExcelExport="true" AllowSelection="false">
        <GridFilterSettings Type="Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.FilterType.FilterBar"></GridFilterSettings>
        <GridPageSettings PageSizes="true"></GridPageSettings>
        <GridSelectionSettings Type="Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.SelectionType.Multiple"></GridSelectionSettings>
        <GridColumns>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SeriLogDTO.Id) HeaderText="ID" IsPrimaryKey="true" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="120"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SeriLogDTO.TimeStamp) HeaderText="TimeStamp" IsPrimaryKey="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="120"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SeriLogDTO.Message) HeaderText="Message" IsPrimaryKey="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="500"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SeriLogDTO.Exception) HeaderText="Exception" IsPrimaryKey="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="200"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SeriLogDTO.MessageTemplate) HeaderText="MessageTemplate" IsPrimaryKey="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="300"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SeriLogDTO.Level) HeaderText="Level" IsPrimaryKey="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="200"></GridColumn>

            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SeriLogDTO.Properties) HeaderText="Properties" IsPrimaryKey="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="200"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field=@nameof(SeriLogDTO.LogEvent) HeaderText="LogEvent" IsPrimaryKey="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="200"></GridColumn>
        </GridColumns>
    </SfGrid>
}

<style>
    .c-error {
        padding: 5px;
        background: #fff0f4;
        color: #c51244;
    }
</style>

@code {

    SfGrid<SeriLogDTO>? Grid;

    private DateTime CurrenTimeLocalStart { get; set; }

    private DateTime CurrenTimeLocalEnd { get; set; }

    public IList<SeriLogDTO>? SeriLogs = null;

    public string Error = null;

    private bool isInitialized = false;


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        CurrenTimeLocalStart = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
        // SeriLogs = await maintenanceStore.ListRelated();
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        CurrenTimeLocalEnd = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
    }
}
```

The other pages in the template project load fine (since there is no async calls?)

**App.Razor**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="App.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes/bootstrap5.css" />
@*     <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes/fluent.css" /> *@
    <script src="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Core/scripts/syncfusion-blazor.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/localStorage.js"></script>
    <script src="js/logoutOnly.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js" autostart="true"></script>
 @*    <script src="js/boot.js"></script> *@

    <script>
        // Wait until a 'reload' button appears https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59779601/auto-reconnect-blazor-serverside
        new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
            if (document.querySelector('#components-reconnect-modal h5 a')) {
                // Now every 10 seconds, see if the server appears to be back, and if so, reload
                async function attemptReload() {
                    await fetch(''); // Check the server really is back
                    location.reload();
                }
                observer.disconnect();
                attemptReload();
                setInterval(attemptReload, 10000);
            }
        }).observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
    </script>
</body>

</html>

<script>

    function isDevice() {

        return /android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini|mobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

    }

</script>
```

**Route.razor:**

```
@using App.Components.Layout
@* <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Client._Imports).Assembly }">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>
 *@

 <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <App.Components.Pages.Account.Login />
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <CascadingAuthenticationState>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </CascadingAuthenticationState>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Comment: *"freezing the screen until first async call is completed?"* - more like utill **all** `async` task completed. that was what I can read from the [blazor lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-8.0)..

Comment: @BagusTesa: Yes I guess so? I added the memory caching change, but it still is the same.

Comment: Serilog is not called "Seri logs". It's just "[Serilog](https://serilog.net/)".

Comment: @Dai: oh, okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Net8 introduced the Rendermode, and with it the ability to create all sorts of variations of static. active and client side rendered pages.

The problem with this choice is it's very easy to get things wrong.

For this answer I've:

1. Deployed a *Blazor Web Project* template with *InteractiveServer* and *Per page/component* options selected.
2. Added the *Blazr.RenderState* Nuget package.
3. Added the *Blazr.RenderState* services to the server.

```cs
builder.AddBlazrRenderStateServerServices();
```

A normal async load page looks like this.  I've used an `await Task.Delay(2000);` to fake a slow async database data get.

```
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@using Blazr.RenderState
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@if (_loading)
{
    <div class="alert alert-warning">Loading</div>
    return;
}


<div class="alert alert-success">Loaded</div>

@code {
    private bool _loading = true;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // emulate slow data load
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        _loading = false;
    }
}
```

When you first run application you will notice:

1. A lag as the page pre-renders.
2. Loaded displayed as the pre-render completes.
3. Loading displayed as the page loads interactively.
4. Loaded after the completion of the await.

If you go to another page and then navigate back you will get the same effect, except in step 1 it will lag on the page you are leaving.

The reason for this is that the application is set to *Per page/component* and the router is being rendered statically on the server. In `App` it's render mode is not set

```cs
    <Routes />
```

It's an SSSR component.

That means that `App`, `Router`, `MainLayout`, `NavMenu` are all SSSR.  It's only `Home` and it's sub-components that are ASSR.

#### `IBlazrRenderStateService`

`IBlazrRenderStateService` detects a pre-render, so we can avoid doing any long running async tasks and display the same loading page.

This version of the page loads immediately and the SSSR to ASSR context switch is much more seamless.

```
@page "/Loader"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@using Blazr.RenderState
@inject IBlazrRenderStateService RenderState
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@if (RenderState.IsPreRender || _loading)
{
    <div class="alert alert-warning">Loading</div>
    return;
}


<div class="alert alert-success">Loaded</div>

@code {
    private bool _loading = true;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // exist early
        if (this.RenderState.IsPreRender)
            return;

        await Task.Delay(2000);
        _loading = false;
    }
}
```

#### OnAfterRender{Async}

`OnAfterRender{Async}` works in this instance because it isn't called when pre-rendering (there's no js context).  However I don't believe it's good practice to use it in this context for the same reasons given in these two questions and answers.

- [Should I use OnAfterRenderAsync instead of OnInitializedAsync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69374767/should-i-use-onafterrenderasync-instead-of-oninitializedasync)
- [Blazor - should I read in my data in OnInitializedAsync() or OnAfterRenderAsync(true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76442472/blazor-should-i-read-in-my-data-in-oninitializedasync-or-onafterrenderasync)

You can find the project and the [Blazr.RenderState Repo here](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.RenderState).

Comment: wow! This seems to work. I tried it locally and it worked perfect. I pushed it to my test azure app service site and it works in Chrome. I tested it on my Samsung S21 mobile phone and it works!  I'll try to report here if I see any issues. Your instructions were perfect to setup up!  Thanks for the comments on why I shouldn't use `OnAfterRender{Async}`