# Blazor 8 InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged) doesn't work in widget

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have upgraded to a Blazor 8 WebAssembly project from a Blazor 7. In my Blazor 7 project I used a component to update the title and SEO information dynamically. The header component code looks like this:

```
@if (headerState is not null && headerState.header is not null)
{
    <PageTitle>@headerState.header.Title</PageTitle>
    <HeadContent>
        <meta name="description" content="@headerState.header.Description">
        <meta name="keywords" content="@headerState.header.Keywords">
        <meta name="og:url" content="@headerState.header.Url">
        <meta name="og:title" content="@headerState.header.Title">
        <meta name="og:description" content="@headerState.header.Description">
        <meta name="og:image" content="@headerState.header.Image">
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="´summary">
        <meta name="twitter:site" content="@headerState.header.TwitterSite">
        <meta name="twitter:text:description" content="@headerState.header.Description">

        <link rel="canonical" href="@headerState.header.Url">
    </HeadContent>
}

public partial class HeaderComponent : IDisposable
{
    [Inject] 
    public PageHeaderState headerState { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        headerState.StateChanged += async (Source, Property) => await HeaderState_StateChanged(Source, Property);
    }

    private async Task HeaderState_StateChanged(ComponentBase Source, string Property)
    {
        if (Source != this)
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        headerState.StateChanged -= async (Source, Property) => await HeaderState_StateChanged(Source, Property);
    }
}
```

I invoke it from then page like this:

```
 protected void LoadHeader(string title, string descr)
 {
     header.Title = $"{title}";
     header.Description = descr;
     header.Keywords = "programs, video, undervisning, dokumentärer, intervjuer, reportage, koncerter, barnprogram";
     header.TwitterSite = "@Sverige";
     header.Url = $"{_navmanager.Uri}";
     header.Image = $"{Config.WbImageUrl}/tv/d4893099-6694-47ff-838e-8fcf6ee72a93.jpg";

     headerState.SetHeader(this, header);
 }
```

I all works fine as long as I place the code on the a razor component that has a @page directive but when I try to invoke it inside a widget nested in the page, I can see the state is changed but it is not reflected in the HeadOutlet and rendered. For example this is a blogpost component  where I try to invoke the new state but nothing happens.

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    headerState.StateChanged += async (Source, Property) => await HeaderState_StateChanged(Source, Property);
}

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    await GetItems();
}

private async Task HeaderState_StateChanged(ComponentBase Source, string Property)
{
    if (Source != this)
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}

protected async Task Navigate(int type)
{
    string url = "";

    if (type == 1)
    {
        url = itemForward.ItemUrl;
    }
    else if (type == 2)
    {
        url = itemBack.ItemUrl;
    }

    _navmanager.NavigateTo($"/bloggar/blogpost/{url}");
}

protected async Task GetItems()
{
    listItem = await _repoListItem.GetSingle(EndPoints.ListItemEndpoint + $"GetByUrl?siteId=5&url={url}");

    if (listItem is not null)
    {
        listItems = await _repoListItem.Get(EndPoints.ListItemEndpoint + $"GetItemsByListPublished?Id={listItem.ListId}&q=5&rowno=1");
        allListItems = await _repoListItem.Get(EndPoints.ListItemEndpoint + $"GetItemsByListPublished?Id={listItem.ListId}&q=0&rowno=1");

        GetNextAndPrevious(allListItems);
        LoadHeader();

        // StateHasChanged();
    }
}

protected void LoadHeader()
{
    header.Title = $"{listItem.Title} | Kanal10.se";
    header.Description = listItem.Descr;
    header.Keywords = "kanal10, kanal 10, kristen, tv, live, gudstjänster, undervisning, dokumentärer, intervjuer, reportage, koncerter, barnprogram";
    header.TwitterSite = "@kanal10Sverige";
    header.Url = $"{_navmanager.Uri}";
    header.Image = Config.ImageUrl + "/" + listItem.ItemImage;

    headerState.SetHeader(this, header);
}

public void Dispose()
{
    headerState.StateChanged -= async (Source, Property) => await HeaderState_StateChanged(Source, Property);
}

protected void GetNextAndPrevious(List<ListItemModel> allListItems)
{
    int index = allListItems.FindIndex(x => x.ListItemId == listItem.ListItemId);
    int fI = 0;

    if (index >= 0)
    {
        fI = index + 1;
    }

    int fB = index - 1;

    if (index >= 0)
    {
        fB = index - 1;
    }
    else 
    { 
        fB = -1; 
    }

    if (fB == -1)
    {
        itemForward = null;
    }
    else
    {
        itemForward = allListItems[fB];
    }

    itemBack = allListItems[fI];
}
```

If anyone has any idea for what has changed in the two versions I'd be grateful.

This is how the App.razor looks like and this is where I've put the Headercomponent:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />

    <!-- Syncfusion -->
    <link href="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes/Bootstrap5.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Owl Carousel -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">

    <!-- Telerik -->
    <script src="_content/Telerik.UI.for.Blazor/js/telerik-blazor.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Telerik.UI.for.Blazor/css/kendo-theme-default/all.css" />

    <!-- Allmänna -->
@*     <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
 *@
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9995bafc85.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lipis/flag-icons@6.6.6/css/flag-icons.min.css" />

    <!-- Egna -->
    @* <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" /> *@
    @* <link href="css/Carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" /> *@
    <link href="css/Custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Inbyggda -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Kanal10.Web.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />

    <HeaderComponent />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes />
    <script>
        window.getDimensions = function () {
            return {
                width: window.innerWidth,
                height: window.innerHeight
            };
        };
    </script>
 

    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor/scripts/syncfusion-blazor.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="/JS/carousel.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What has changed - **RenderMode**.  How did you "Upgrade"?  Are you WASM Standalone or Hosted?  Where are you setting the rendermode in your component tree?

Comment: I created a new project based o the new Blazor web app template and choose Wasm as rendering method. Not a standalone project.
As for now I added my header component right before the HeadOutlet in the App.razor component, but I've also tried to place it on my Index page and in the individual razor components I have nested on the page. I have not changed the code in anyway, just created the new project copied the code for the layout and code for the Index page. Then I attached the razor class library (that I've also updated to Net 8).

Comment: What "Interactive location" did you select?  If you can't remember just put your `App.razor` in the question.  I'm just making sure I understand your render mode settings before I answer.

Comment: I've added the App.raqzor code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't strictly done an upgrade.  The closest `Blazor Web App` configuration to the Net7 Hosted WASM template has these settings:

[image]

You chose *Per page/component* which is the default until you've changed it to something else.   You can verify this by checking the setting on the `Route` component in *App.razor*.

Yours looks like this:

```cs
    <Routes />
```

Which means the router is being rendered in `Static SSR` mode.  Only individual pages within the `MainLayout` component that specify their render mode as `InteractiveWebAssembly` are being rendered in `CSR` mode.

If you set *App.razor* like this then it should render correctly:

```
    <HeaderComponent  @rendermode="@InteractiveWebAssembly" />
    <HeadOutlet  @rendermode="@InteractiveWebAssembly" />

    <Routes @rendermode="@InteractiveWebAssembly" />
```

You may also be able to set the Header info directly in `HeadOutlet` using `<HeadContent>` like this:

```cs
<PageTitle>@title</PageTitle>

<HeadContent>
    <meta name="description" content="@description">
</HeadContent>
```

See this similar question:

[Blazor Server / .NET 8 / Calling async code on initial load is freezing the screen until first async call is completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77649966/blazor-server-net-8-calling-async-code-on-initial-load-is-freezing-the-scre)

And this answer and Github site that demonstrates how to get the render mode of a component:

[Blazor .Net 8 splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77653261/blazor-net-8-splash-screen/77659356#77659356)

https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.RenderState