How can I change the value in EditForm by code?
Here is the html:
 <EditForm Model="Input" method="post" OnValidSubmit="LoginUser" FormName="login" Enhance>
     <DataAnnotationsValidator />
     <div id="SubmitDiv">
         <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Email" class="ant-input SubmitContentInput" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" placeholder="@_Localizer["ErrorMessageUserNameRequire"]" />
         <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Email" class="ant-form-item-explain-error" />
         <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Password" type="password" class="ant-input SubmitContentInput" autocomplete="current-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="@_Localizer["ErrorMessagePasswordRequire"]" />
         <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Password" class="ant-form-item-explain-error" />
     </div>     
 </EditForm>

And here is the model:
  [SupplyParameterFromForm]
  private InputModel Input { get; set; } = new();

 private sealed class InputModel
 {        
     [EmailAddress(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMessageEMailVerify", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(TuskyPhoenix.Resources.Components.Account.Pages.Login))]
     [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMessageUserNameRequire", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(TuskyPhoenix.Resources.Components.Account.Pages.Login))]
     public string Email { get; set; } = "";

     [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMessagePasswordRequire", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(TuskyPhoenix.Resources.Components.Account.Pages.Login))]
     [DataType(DataType.Password)]
     public string Password { get; set; } = "";
 }

And here is the code to set the value:
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        var _uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(_NavigationManager.Uri);
        var _query = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(_uriBuilder.Query);
        var _result = _query["UserName"];
        if (_result is { })
        {
            Input.Email = _result;
        }
    }
}

When the user input the URL "https://localhost:1434/Account/login?UserName=abc@Gmail.com"
It can get the query parameter abc@Gmail.com successfully.
However, after setting the value of Input.Email to the query parameter, the UI doesn't change any.
What I actually want to do is to input the email by URL.
What's wrong with my code? Is it only a one-way binding? How can I implement this?

Net version?  Interactivity type and location?  But basically the code you currently have in OnAfterRenderAsync in OnInitialized.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis .Net 8 with Blazor Web App and the rendermode of this page is InteractiveServer.

Move the code to OnInitialized - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69374767/should-i-use-onafterrenderasync-instead-of-oninitializedasync

NP.  I added my comment as an answer for you to tick along with the links to explain why.

You need to move your code to OnInitialized.  The following questions and answers provide the reasons why.

Should I use OnAfterRenderAsync instead of OnInitializedAsync?

Blazor - should I read in my data in OnInitializedAsync() or OnAfterRenderAsync(true)


